# Use sort_by in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I sort a MySQL table and display it in HTML using sort_by in Ruby (by values "views")?

```
My display code is:

<html>
....
..

<% @f_videos.each do |f_video| %>
   <display code .......>

...
..
</html>
```

will this work?

```
f_videos.replace f_videos.sort_by {views}
```

?

Answer (score 5):

It's not very clear what the structure of your data is, but if possible, you should just use the `order` method when looking up objects rather than using `sort_by`.

```
@f_videos = Video.order(:views)
```

Comment: ...do this in your controller